# How to automatically open a "accordion" to first selection?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I bought a template with what seems to be an accordion (custom maybe?) and I am trying to get the first page (accordion slide) to open automatically.

He is the code:

```
 Cufon.now();
$(window).load(function(){

     $('#content>dd').css({display:'block'})


     $('#thumbs').jScrollPane({
       showArrows:false,
       scrollbarWidth:28,
       dragMaxHeight:82
    })

     $('#thumbs li a').live('click',function(){
        $('#pic').attr('src',$(this).attr('href')).bind('load',function(){
            $(this).css({opacity:0}).stop().animate({opacity:1})
        })
        return false
    }).each(function(){
        var tmp=new Image()
        tmp.src=this.href
    })

    $('#content>dd').css({display:'none'})
})

$(function(){
    $('#content:not(.nav_block)>dt:not(.active) a,footer .privacy:not(.active) a[rel=privacy],a[rel=nav]').live('click',function(){
        var next=this.rel=='privacy'?$('#privacy'):this.rel=='nav'?$(this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf('#'))):$(this).parent().next(),
            width=next.width(),
            parent=next.parent(),
            visible=parent.find('>dd:visible').css({overflow:'hidden'})
        parent.addClass('nav_block')
        $('#content>dt,.privacy').removeClass('active')
        $(this).parent().addClass('active')
        if(this.rel=='privacy'||this.rel=='nav')$('#content>dt>a').removeClass('active').animate({opacity:0})
        if(parent.css('left')!=0)
            next.parent().animate({left:0})
        next.show().css({width:'64px'}).stop().animate({width:width+'px'},{
          step:visible.length?function(now){
            visible.width(width-now)
        }:'',complete:function(){
            next.css({overflow:'visible'})
            visible.css({width:width+'px'}).hide()
            parent.removeClass('nav_block')
        }})
        return false
    })

    $('.active a,#content.nav_block').live('click',function(){
        return false
    })

    var imgs=[]
    $('#page1 img').each(function(){
        imgs.push(this)
    })
    $(imgs[0]).siblings('img').css({opacity:0})

    $('#page1 a.prev,#page1 a.next').css({opacity:0}).live('click',function(){
        var img,pr=$(imgs[0])
        if($(this).hasClass('next'))
            imgs.push(imgs.shift())
        else
            imgs.unshift(imgs.pop())
        img=$(imgs[0]).show()
        img.animate({opacity:1},{step:function(now){
            pr.css({opacity:1-now})
        }})
        return false
    })

    $('#page1 .inner')
        .live('mouseover',function(){$('a.prev,a.next',this).stop().animate({opacity:1})})
        .live('mouseout',function(){$('a.prev,a.next',this).stop().animate({opacity:0})})

    $('#content>dt>a:not(.active)').css({opacity:0})
    .live('mouseover',function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1})
    })
    .live('mouseout',function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0})
    })
    .live('click',function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').parent().siblings().find('>a').removeClass('active').stop().animate({opacity:0})
    })
})
```

Any help is appreciated, I have looked through endless threads and all have solutions that didn't work (why I think it's a custom accordion or something).  I am entry level with jQuery, I know basic Java, VB, Objective C so not a complete newbie but go easy :).

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Without seeing the actual page it's pretty difficult to guess what to do. Don't you have a link somewhere to the template ?

Comment: Absolutely, sorry for leaving that out. http://thebuzzformen.com/ I just want the MAIN area to be open when people visit the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by issuing a click on the "MAIN" header programmatically:

```
// this will trigger a 'click' event on the first element (which is the "MAIN")
$('#content dt:first a').trigger('click');
```

Add this line at the end of your script, before the last `});`.

**More info on:**

- [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)
- [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Comment: You are a hero!  Thanks a lot. If anyone lands on this thread looking for help...I had to make one tweak.. I put it right  before the end of the script and all the menu options slide over on load but didn't open up.  I moved it to the end of the window.load function and it works like a charm!  I can't thank you enough!